# Find ALL matching words in a cell with range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I had this formula working correctly in Excel, but when I'm trying to do the same in Google Sheets, it's not having it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(People2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(People2,D2)),""))
```

I have used Exceljet, precisely as described here:
https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-which-things

The formula tries to match words in my "dictionary" in People2 to words in cell D2, and lists all matching ones.

I have set up everything in name manager, works perfectly in Excel.

When I'm trying to do the same in Google Sheet, I get the following error:
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 211, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

The only thing I'm doing differently is now I have the name range in a separate sheet.

I've found posts on how to fix this error, but none seem to apply to my scenario as my range is on a separate sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a description of relevant spreadsheet structure details (i.e. the reference of People2), some sample data and the corresponding expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using multiple cell formula

```
    =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IF(A2="",,SPLIT(A2," ")),{
              TEXTJOIN("|",,QUERY({$D$2:$D}, "Where Col1 is not null"))}),"")),"where Col1 is not null "))),""))
```

[image]

### Using Arrayformula

> **Note**: for a simplified example checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379593/19529694)

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
       IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(A2:A," ")),TEXTJOIN("|",,QUERY({$D$2:$D}, "Where Col1 is not null"))),"")="",,
       IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(A2:A," ")),TEXTJOIN("|",,QUERY({$D$2:$D}, "Where Col1 is not null"))),"")&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]