# Concatenate non empty cells in each row with arrayformula in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, flatten

I have a range of values and empty cells `A2:F15` I want to concatenate only non empty cells using a single formula `Arrayformula`, [Make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7veUkK6h7WKo445fypNbCb7PHDrZQcOElZLC-P3nkc/copy) of this example sheet.

I created this formula but it's not an array based

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:F2)," where Col1 is not null ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use query smash:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:F="",,A2:F&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

Comment: Excellent solution. I have an extra question, though: what if, besides achieving what your formula does, we would want to add, for each non empty cell, the contents of its corresponding header. In the example the columns A to F there's a merged cell with "Input", but let's imagine there are 6 heather cells with "Input A", "Input B" etc. Also, joining them with a different separator than the comma, for instance ":". Let's say that in the first result we would get:  Input A: nSM, Input D: Egk, Input F: kfPR, and in seond row in results:  Input F: Xtv.      Would that be possible? Thanks