# Is there a way to concatenate non empty cells combined with the corresponding header, with different separators and with one single formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an unsolved situation like the one described in the following diagram.

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

Basically it's an array of cells from column A to E, some of them filled, others empty, and I would like to find a formula to get the results in red which work as follows:
For each non empty cell, the result takes the corresponding cell in the header, and combines them with the first separator ": " located in cell I1. Then it joins this combination with the next one, including the next non empty cell with its header. This process until it reaches the last column. All the combinations have be joined by the second separator, located in cell I2.
An added value to the formula would be to include each non empty cell within quotes, for instance:  **Town: "Madrid",** 
Finally, and if possible, the results might be achieved by using one formula in a top cell only, avoiding formula that need to be dragged down. Index, Arrayformula or flatten/query functions would be suitable, in a similar way to the solution found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379593/concatenate-non-empty-cells-in-each-row-with-arrayformula-in-google-sheets):

=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:F="",,A2:F&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))

That's all.
Thank you so much for your help.
Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(A2:E,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,join(I2&" ",filter(A1:E1&I1&" """&z&"""",z<>"")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. thanks so much!! Your solution is so elegant too. I am posing the same comment to you as well: is there a way to use the quotes only for certain columns in the array?. for instance only in column Town and column Phone, leaving us with: Country: Malaysia, Town: "Kuala Lumpur", Street: Main st, Phone: "1234567". Thanks again.

Comment: try: `=byrow(A2:E,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,join(I2&" ",filter(A1:E1&I1&if(regexmatch(A1:E1,"Town|Phone")," """&z&""""," "&z),z<>"")))))`

Comment: One last question, if I may. With the above formula working with quotes, what if we would also want to exclude certain header contents and its corresponding separator. F.i.. excluding the header cell "Town" and "ZIP CODE", meaning that we might get: Country: Malaysia, "Kuala Lumpur", Street: Main st, 92111, Phone: "1234567". See that the ZIP code column result has no quotes (92111), but the Town resualt has quotes "Kuala Lumpur". Just to overcomplicate a bit the situation. Thanks again.

Comment: go with: `=byrow(A2:E,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,join(I2&" ",filter(if(regexmatch(A1:E1,"Town|ZIP"),,A1:E1&I1&" ")&if(regexmatch(A1:E1,"Town|Phone"),""""&z&"""",""&z),z<>"")))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this formula. If you want not to hardcode the separators, change them to a cell reference like in your graphic:

```
={"Result";BYROW(A2:E,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r)=0,"",TEXTJOIN(", ",1,BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,IF(LEN(c),INDEX(A1:E1,,COLUMN(c))&": """&c&"""","")))))))}
```

[image]

With the Separators:

```
={"Result";BYROW(A2:E,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r)=0,"",TEXTJOIN(J1,1,BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,IF(LEN(c),INDEX(A1:E1,,COLUMN(c))&J2&""""&c&"""","")))))))}
```

[image]

Comment: I am thinking, is there a way to use the quotes only for certain columns in the array?. for instance only in column Town and column Phone, leaving us with:  Country: Malaysia, Town: "Kuala Lumpur", Street: Main st, Phone: "1234567".   Thanks again.